# Save pdf to file with protractor

Tags: javascript, pdf, selenium-webdriver, browser, protractor

I need to save pdf to file. Problem is that after clicking `Print` button on my page it redirects me to a new page with pdf in it. This is good for a user because it is a standard chrome pdf viewer, but the problem is that I cannot click `download` button, because the only html I can see is this:

```
<body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0">
     <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="blob:https://myPage.com/e8aa96bf-5a46-4f74-8df6-424881a8774a" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="34" title="">
</body>
```

Anyone knows how to download a pdf in protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a pdf involves using HTML 5 `download` attribute. We can create an `a` element than will save the pdf for us when we click on it.

Basically we need to create our own `<a download="ourfile.pdf" href="blob:ourPath">` where `download` is the name of the file we want to save, and `href` is the url of our `pdf`, or `src` attribute of `embed`.

We can create this element using `browser.driver.executeScript();`. So we can create something like this:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.executeScript(`var a = document.createElement('a');
                                      a.href = arguments[0];
                                      a.id="downloadPdf";
                                      a.download = "abc.pdf";
                                      a.text="DOWNLOAD"
                                      a.style="width:200px;height:200px;"
                                      var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                                      b.insertBefore(a, b.firstChild);
                                      `,
            browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).then(() => {
                browser.driver.findElement(by.id('downloadPdf')).click();
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
            });
    });
});
```

We pass `url` with second argument and insert our new element as the first element of `body`. Then we find our newly created element and click.

We can also specify path to where our files should be saved. This is done by setting `default_directory` in our config file.

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': 'C:\\your\\custom\\path\\',
            }
        }
    },
  }
```

Comment: Hi.. The code works perfect. But I want to download the file with different name other than the default name. I did change the file name in a.download of script. But it doesnt wok. Can you please help me with this